# How to remove variables from a graph in tensorflow? or how to remove a graph and release the memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In my algorithm, I need to create a graph iteratively and use shared variables.
The problem is that every time that I create a graph and use shared variables, Tensorflow creates new variables and allocates memory to them. This causes a growth in the used memory. Obviously at some point it consumes all the memory and gets killed.

So the solution is either of these:

1- Remove the variables created in the previous iteration and release the memory. Then create the new graph. But how?

2- After every iteration delete the graph and create, release the memory, and create a new one. But then I need to some how store the variables somewhere so that I can use them for creating the next graph (because variables are shared). But how?

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow supports resetting a session. See [reset in the session management](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) for how to use it.